# What early-2000s show about dimension hopping has a character who can swap limbs?

Tags: story-identification

An earlier question asked about a show that made me think of another one I can't remember.  It was a live action show about exploring different dimensions, and I think the main character was searching for his dad.  I remember seeing it in the US, but I don't know if it was limited to that.

I'm a little fuzzy on the details, but I think the main character could swap his limbs or something like that.

Comment: @Jonah Oh my, there it is. I had forgotten about it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### Galidor: Defenders of the Outer Dimension

As noted [here](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Series/Galidor):

> Nick's special ability allows him to exchange his limbs with other
>   beings, an ability which works properly a very small percentage of the
>   time.

Nick's  father has disappeared, and there is certainly dimension travelling.

Comment: Dude, TV Tropes warning!  But wow, I forgot that there were some pretty corny looking characters.

Answer (score 5):

Could it be https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galidor:_Defenders_of_the_Outer_Dimension? Us and Canada, time seems right, even mentions the changing limbs.

Answer (score -1):

Might you be thinking of [*Sliders*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sliders) (1995–2000)?

[image]

(Although *Sliders* didn’t feature any limb-swapping, as far as I know.)

Comment: No, this show came out in like 2001, and was more a kids show.

Comment: Sliders was kind of a kids' show...