# Looking for an old TV show where a group of 4 characters (boy, girl, blue guy, robot?) travel to different dimensions

Tags: story-identification, tv

I remember watching a live-action TV show around the late 90's or early 00's. It centered around four main characters: a boy, a girl, a blue guy who might have been furry and a robot (I think). They would travel through different dimensions (I specifically remember the word dimensions being used). I think the premise was that the boy was looking for his dad(?).

I think I watched this show on the family channel so it may have aired on Disney in the US. I also distinctly remember there being a line of McDonald's toys based on the show where you could mix and match the parts from the different characters (possibly an ability that the boy had).

Comment: I forgot to mention that it was a live action series. Thanks for trying though!

Comment: You might want to have a hunt through my checklist here to see if there's anything else you can think of regarding the characters, names, situations, etc; http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found your answer. *[Galidor: Defenders of the Outer Dimension](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Series/Galidor)*. It's covered in [What early-2000s show about dimension hopping has a character who can swap limbs?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/129910/what-early-2000s-show-about-dimension-hopping-has-a-character-who-can-swap-limbs) on this site. Nick's special ability allows him to exchange his limbs with other beings, an ability which works properly a very small percentage of the time and his father is missing.

[image: Gallidor image]

It did indeed run on ABC Family, and there were licensed Lego toys (Lego partially funded it) which were offered in McDonalds Happy Meals:

The show nearly bankrupted Lego at the time, in part because it used a lot of concepts that were ahead of their time like promotion through an Alternate Reality Game, embedded white noise sound effects that triggered the toys, and extensive CGI (hamstrung by a low budget).

Comment: Well, if it's not this, then the makers of this need to **sue the hell** out of whatever he's describing.

Comment: Which, admittedly, does happen from time to time. :) By the way, thank you for editing my other answer, but I deleted it because Galidor was so obviously the actual answer.

Comment: I voted to undelete it. It's a reasonable match and it might help future searchers looking for something similar, but not the same...

Comment: I guess that is true.

Comment: That's it! man, that has been bothering me for so long. Thank you so much!

Comment: Oh my god; I have all but one of these lego figures. Never had any clue what they were from.

Answer (score 3):

The time frame and a boy traveling through multiple dimensions automatically made me think of ***[Josh Kirby... Time Warrior!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josh_Kirby..._Time_Warrior!)*** but that was a boy, a girl, a old professor, and a warrior, pursued by a man in power armor, and I don't think they did any McDonald's toys. Still, I figure it's worth proffering as a guess.