# Looking for early 2000's show about teenage boy and girl stuck on an icy planet

Tags: story-identification, tv

I can't remember much about it as a kid, but I do remember the toys and its really bugging me.

I watched in in the early 2000's before *Doctor Who* in 2005 as well as *Ace Lightning*, so it may have been on CBBC.

I only remember that it was live action, about this teenage boy and girl who where stuck on another world (kind of icy or at least there were icy worlds) and the guy can somehow change his limbs to be mechanical. There was a scene where the girl is being taken by the lead villain and as he reaches out for her, his arm transforms into a spring like arm that springs forwards and saves her to his suprise.

There was also a silver C-3PO-looking robot and a giant bird-like creature (I think) as their allies in a pod like spaceship.

There was once en episode where the pod could only use its legs for some reason and had to walk instead of fly.

The toys were really cool and easily available in the UK, and you could detach all the limbs to mix and match different characters since that's what the characters do in the show. Kind of Like LEGO but proper figures.

Comment: Welcome to the site. You have a good start here. If you could take a look at this [guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/62201) to help jog your memory and [edit] in any more details, that would be great. Every little bit helps us.

Comment: If possible include more information in the title. "A childhood show" is not specific. When was your childhood? Better write something like "Early 2000's show about teenage boy and girl stuck in an icy planet?"

Comment: What the show live action or animated? You saw it as a child, but what age group was it targeted at?

Comment: The show was live action. I'd say it was was targeted to 6 - 13 year olds. It wasn't exactly scary

Answer (score 4):

You are most likely looking for *[Galidor: Defenders of the Outer Dimension](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0310457/)*.

It has all of the elements you specified.  The show aired on Fox Kids (before they changed their name) during the Saturday morning cartoon schedule.

[image: Cover photo]

Comment: Can you possibly show/provide descriptions of scenes matching the elements described?

Comment: If so, it will be a dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/129915/23243