# Teenage boy travels to another planet/dimension where the ruler can transform his arms and body parts into weapons

Tags: story-identification, tv

Early 2000s sci-fi show, maybe late 1990s. A teenage boy and his friend, I think she was a black or Spanish girl. The boy ends up going to another planet or dimension. I think he was looking for his father.

The ruler of this world has the power to transform his arms and body parts into weapons.

The boy later on finds out he has the same abilities as well. I believe the boy and his friend were able to travel back and forth between Earth and the other place.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. This sounds similar to the premise of various cartoons, so just to be clear, was this live-action or animated?

Answer (score 2):

This is ***[Galidor: Defenders of the Outer Dimension](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0310457/)*** (2002), a Lego branded cartoon for the tie-in toyline.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galidor:_Defenders_of_the_Outer_Dimension):

> *Galidor: Defenders of the Outer Dimension*, sometimes shortened as *Galidor*, is a 2002 television series that ran on YTV in Canada and Fox Kids in the United States in 2002 with a total of 26 half-hour episodes. The series was created by Thomas W. Lynch, the creator of *The Secret World of Alex Mack* and *The Journey of Allen Strange*; and funded and owned by the Lego Group. It was the final series to launch on Fox Kids, as the brand folded in the United States only 7 months after its debut.

The main character is teenage boy Nick Bluetooth, accompanied by fellow teen Allegra Zane and several rebels from the outer dimension, who use 'Glinching' to transform their limbs to fight the evil conqueror Gorm and search for Nick's father.

Comment: If so, it would be a dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/129910/what-early-2000s-show-about-dimension-hopping-has-a-character-who-can-swap-limbs?noredirect=1&lq=1. This one comes up periodically, and is actually a fascinating look at what happens when a show is ahead of its time (and execution is bungled).

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CnzbArJuBV4 for an overview.